# January 1st = Week 1

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The below gives me **week numbers** where week 1 starts on 1/4/2021

```
date_trunc('week', transaction_date)     as week_number
```

1. How can I create a week_number where the week starts on January 1st and counts up 7 days for every week thereafter (for every year)?
2. And round up/down to 52 weeks at the end of the year?

Code attempted:
This doesn't give me the answer, but I'm thinking something like this might work...

`ceil(extract(day from transaction_date)/7)    as week_number`

Expected Output:

| transaction_date | week_number |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | 1 |
| 1/8/2020 | 2 |
| ... | ... |
| 12/31/2020 | 52 |
| 1/1/2021 | 1 |
| 1/8/2021 | 2 |
| ... | ... |
| 12/27/2021 | 52 |
| 12/28/2021 | 52 |
| 12/29/2021 | 52 |
| 12/30/2021 | 52 |
| 12/31/2021 | 52 |
| 1/1/2022 | 1 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry yeah it's snowflake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use date arithmetic:

```
select 1 + (transaction_date - date_trunc('year', transaction_date)) / 7 as year_week
```

Comment: Beautiful and simple code. Thanks so much, @Gordon!!

Answer (score 0):

> The below gives me week numbers where week 1 starts on 1/4/2021

It is the default behaviour and it is defined that way in ISO.

[WEEK_OF_YEAR_POLICY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#week-of-year-policy)

> Type     Session — Can be set for Account » User » Session
>
> Description
>
> Specifies how the weeks in a given year are computed.
> Values
>
> **0: The semantics used are equivalent to the ISO semantics, in which a week belongs to a given year if at least 4 days of that week are in that year.**
>
> 1: January 1 is included in the first week of the year and December 31 is included in the last week of the year.
>
> **Default    0 (i.e. ISO-like behavior)**

It could be overrriden on multiple levels. The most granular is on the session level:

```
ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_OF_YEAR_POLICY = 1;
```

Then you could use the standard code:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', transaction_date)     as week_number
FROM ...;
```