# Calendar date column in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake that looks like this:

```
starting_date   fiscal_week   calendar_week
2020-12-31      53            53
2021-01-01      53            53
2021-01-08      53            01
```

The `fiscal_week` and `calendar_week` look up off of the `starting_date` (format is YYYYMMDD). The fiscal week should follow the 1-53 week number in the year. The calendar_week does not necessarily need to start off on a Sunday, it just needs to start off on the first day of the year as week 01.

Thus, I would like it to look like this:

```
starting_date   fiscal_week   calendar_week
2020-12-31      53            53
2021-01-01      53            01
2021-01-08      53            02
```

I've tried using the weekiso and week functions such as below but still am not getting the desired results. The results still reflect what is shown in the first table.

`select *, weekiso (starting_date) as calendar_week from my table`

Is there a specific way to do this in the snowflake database? I'm assuming that's where my issue is coming from but I'm not sure.

I'm new to using snowflake so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [January 1st = Week 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67893921/5070879) - **WEEK_OF_YEAR_POLICY**

Answer (score 2):

You can extract days of the year and do some arithmetic on that. It's probably easier to just change the week of year policy at session level though

```
select floor((dayofyear(starting_date)+6)/7)
```